# Node-Red chart node with stored data

Tags: node.js, node-red

I have a problem with the chart node. I want to display a line graph, the data source is two MQTT messages. A microcontroller publishes two 2049 element byte arrays in 2 topics (linearccdL and linearccdH). The data are upper and lower bytes of words, and at first I have to join them, it works now.
When the 2049 pcs 16 bit numbers are ready i have to display them on a graph. According to the documentation, the graph node accepts arrays in the form:

```
[{
"series": ["A", "B", "C"],
"data": [
    [{ "x": 1504029632890, "y": 5 },
     { "x": 1504029636001, "y": 4 },
     { "x": 1504029638656, "y": 2 }
    ],
    [{ "x": 1504029633514, "y": 6 },
     { "x": 1504029636622, "y": 7 },
     { "x": 1504029639539, "y": 6 }
    ],
    [{ "x": 1504029634400, "y": 7 },
     { "x": 1504029637959, "y": 7 },
     { "x": 1504029640317, "y": 7 }
    ]
],
"labels": [""]
}]
```

I'm using a `function` to format the data:

```
var rawDataL = new ArrayBuffer(2049);
var rawDataH = new ArrayBuffer(2049);
var rawData = new Uint16Array(2049);
var outobj = {};
var outarr = [];
var outmsg;

if (msg.topic == "rbmt/linearccdL") {
    context.rawDataL = msg.payload;
    context.Lset=true;
} else if (msg.topic == "rbmt/linearccdH") {
    context.rawDataH = msg.payload;
    context.Hset=true;
}
if (context.Lset & context.Hset) {
    for (var i=0; i<2049; i++) {
        rawData[i]=context.rawDataH[i]*256+context.rawDataL[i];
        outobj={"x":i, "y":rawData[i]};
        outarr.push(outobj);

    }
    context.Lset=false;
    context.Hset=false;
    outmsg = {"series":"[A]", data: outarr};
    return outmsg;
}
```

After putting a `debug` node i can see the message, seems OK, but on the dashboard i get "No data".
I'm new in JS, can somebody help a bit please?
The debug message: [debug msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GX30k.png)

Comment: The ui_chart node expects your data to be in `msg.payload`, but you are returning an object with fields "series" and "data". It looks like you just need to put the generated data into the existing payload -- so change the 2nd to last line to be `msg.payload = {"series":"[A]", data: outarr};` and then `return msg;`

Comment: There is the point! But doesn't work. Still "No data" on the dasboard. I've attached the screenshot of the debug msg to the post, hope it helps.

Comment: In the image of the debug output, I can see that your "data" field is an array of length 2049 -- since you only have one series "A", your data must contain an array of 1 element, which would then contain all your data points (an array of arrays). Ignore my previous code example and try this instead:
`msg.payload = { "series": ["A"], data: [outarr] };`

Comment: Incidentally, trying to push thousands of data points into the ui_chart node is going to cause you either memory issues or display problems. You should really think about downsampling your data, by limiting the time range, or by binning the timestamps into larger chunks and aggregating the values.

Comment: It works now, many thanks for the help! But it's very slooooww, takes tens of seconds to react to a message. I've written a small c program instead to do the visualization (with libmosquitto and gnuplot).

Comment: Dashboard's charting is somewhat limited in performance right now. You can use a different chart library which can handle more data or maybe switch to an alternate presentation tool. For example, you could pass your MQTT data into something like InfluxDB as time series data and then chart it using Grafana which intelligently handles very large datasets.